# How can I align a checkbox with inputs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I would like to align a checkbox with the rest of the inputs, actually it's like aligned with label.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="row g-3">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputPassword4" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label for="inputAddress" class="form-label">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="inputAddress2" class="form-label">Address 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">City</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="inputState" class="form-label">State</label>
    <select id="inputState" class="form-select">
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option>...</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
            Check me out
          </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/td1479L5/

Comment: What do you mean by align?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the column a flex container, then justify the checkbox group to end. I added a bit of bottom margin to the group as well. Adjust that to suit your preference.

Note that I also tweaked the column classes for better mobile presentation.

View the full page demo to see it in action.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="row g-3">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputPassword4" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-6">
    <label for="inputAddress" class="form-label">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="inputAddress2" class="form-label">Address 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">City</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="inputState" class="form-label">State</label>
    <select id="inputState" class="form-select">
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option>...</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col col-md-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
    <div class="form-check mb-2">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
        Check me out
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure I understand the question correctly, but perhaps this is what you wanted? The adress input fields now change from inline to block at the same time as the usern/pass input fields.

https://jsfiddle.net/officernickwilde/fak53y2r/

```js
<style>
.expanding-form-entry {
  min-width: 385px;
  flex-grow:1;
}</style>
<form class="row g-3">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputPassword4" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 expanding-form-entry">
    <label for="inputAddress" class="form-label">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 expanding-form-entry">
    <label for="inputAddress2" class="form-label">Address 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">City</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="inputState" class="form-label">State</label>
    <select id="inputState" class="form-select">
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option>...</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="inputZip" class="form-label">Zip</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
        Check me out
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be writing custom styles for things like this. The library provides mechanisms for layout alignment. Also, hard-coded widths like that are problematic in responsive layouts.